# Improve SSD reliability with NTFS but no TRIM support

Tags: ssd, filesystems, ntfs

I have an SSD with a single NTFS partition, but I access it through an external USB interface and there is no TRIM support.

My question is: Does NTFS attempt to reuse previously used sectors when creating new files (i.e. sectors that used to be occupied by now-deleted files), or does it specifically try to cover the entire drive and leave deleted space untouched?

If the latter, is there some magic file system option tweaks that can make it behave like the former (I ask because Windows seems to have a lot of obscure file system tools and tweaks, and I'm often surprised)?

Alternatively, is there a file system that behaves this way (prefers to reuse previously used space rather than preserving deleted data) that is compatible with Windows?

My goal is to extend the reliability of the SSD as much as possible in a situation where TRIM on file delete is not available. I did trim the entire device before formatting it and putting it in the USB enclosure, but eventually that space will all be touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing is to leave some `free space` to extend SSD endurance. 
The TRIM's task is to indicate sectors which are treated by OS as deleted. This function is only like support for controller's GC (garbage collector), it doesn't replace it. GC will care about previously written sectors which are in queue to erase and rewrite. In what schedule it proceeds depends on used algorithms.